# Ionic show button if Storage key = true

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic-storage

how to show button if Ionic Storage `isLogin` = `true`.

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
constructor(
    private storage: Storage,
) { }

login(phone: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`/api/user/login`, { phone, password })
        .pipe(map(user => {
            this.storage.set('currentUser', user);
            this.storage.set('isLogin', true);
            this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
            return user;
        }));
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.storage.get('isLogin').then(result => {
        this.isLoginVal = result
        console.log(this.isLoginVal)
    })
}

<button mat-icon-button (click)="goToLogin()" *ngIf="!isLoginVal; else logged">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
</button>

<ng-template #logged>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="drawer()">
        <mat-icon>user</mat-icon>
    </button>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: what is `this.storage` ? Are you trying to set value in `localStorage` of the browser? Please let me know.

Comment: storage = ionic storage, i have updated the question.

Comment: Can you tell me when your `login` function called? I can see that you are trying to get the `isLogin` inside `ngOnInit` function. `ngOnInit` invoked almost beginning of this component. Please let me know. :-)

Comment: login function is use for login form. If login successful, set Ionic Storage 'isLogin' = 'true', else 'false'. If Ionic Storage 'isLogin' = 'true' show ng-template '#logged'